# Redis Vector cosine similarity using javascript

Tags: javascript, redis, cosine-similarity, ioredis

I'm trying to do a redis search based on vector cosine similarity using javascript, I found library [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) that allow me to interact with redis cache on azure but can't find a way to do a search, I did it on C# or Python but nothing on javascript. Can anyone please show me the way using ioredis library or any other javascript one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that ioredis has support for RediSearch. [Node Redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) is the officially supported and maintained client for Redis and it *does* support search. And JSON and probabilisitic data structures to boot.

It's just a quick `npm instal redis` away.